# Reinstall Yosemite on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have bought Macbook with Lion, which I have upgraded to Yosemite. Now I want to reinstall Yosemite from stratch. Which Mac OS version will be installed if I'll follow [this instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18872?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) (Command (⌘) and R keys).

Will it install Lion (which was installed on my Mac Air when I have bought it) or will be downloaded last version - Yosemite?

How can I install Yosemite from stratch?

Answer (score 1):

From [OS X: About OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

> Which version of OS X is installed by OS X Recovery?
>
> - If you use the Recovery System stored on your startup drive to    reinstall OS X, it installs the most recent version of OS X previously installed on this computer.
> - If you use Internet Recovery to reinstall OS X, it installs the version of OS X that originally came with your computer. After installation is finished, use the [Mac App Store](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338) to install related updates or later versions of OS X that you have previously purchased.

So as long as the local Recovery disk partition is intact it will install, at this point in time, OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.